# Im trying to make a website, javascript math doesn't work

Tags: javascript, calculation

I'm trying to use codepen.io to make a website to sell things (not really "sell" things), but for some reason the calculations with the javascript won't work, I'm trying to make it calculate the total and display it in a text-field. Here is the javascript.

```
function doFunction(){

   var shirtNo, bearNo, pillowNo, totalNo; 
   var shirtNo =  document.getElementById("panda_shirt").value;
   bearNo = document.getElementById("panda_toy").value;
   pillowNo =    document.getElementById("panda_pillow").value;
   var totalQty = panda_shirt + panda_toy + panda_pillow ,
     estimateTotal;
   estimateTotal = ($14 * panda_shirt) + ($12 * panda_toy) + ($10 * 
   panda_pillow);
  
   document.getElementById('estimateTotal').value = Estimate Total;
}
```

Comment: `value` returns strings not numbers. Need to convert to number to do your addition `"1" + "1" = "11"` the same way that `"a" + "b" = "ab"` due to string concatention

Comment: Javascript values don't have units, such as $.So do the calculations as numbers then display the $ and the number.

Comment: Thank you guys! If you guys could go to here. https://codepen.io/bodaciousbear/pen/GXyJwM and look at my code that would be very much appreciated. It doesn't look the nicest, but its just for fun so....

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors. Try the code below. This will give you the total price, then you can use it however you'd like.

```
  function doFunction(){ 
     var shirtNo =  document.getElementById("panda_shirt").value;
     var bearNo = document.getElementById("panda_toy").value;
     var pillowNo = document.getElementById("panda_pillow").value;
     var estimateTotal = (14 * Number(shirtNo)) + (12 * Number(bearNo)) + (10 * Number(pillowNo));
```

Comment: Explaning why the solution works is helpful to the entire community.

Answer (score 0):

'$14' is not a number.

computers are perfect at math. that's their primary function. so if the math is wrong, it's your code, not the computer or the language.

also you have not defined `panda_shirt` or your other variables, so it appears you are attempting to do math with undefined objects.

try adding `console.log()` statements to your code so you can see what variable values you are dealing with.

Comment: Written without quotes (as in OP code) it would actually be interpreted as an undefined variable, not a string

Comment: *computers are perfect at math* then try `0.1 + 0.2` in JS.

Comment: @connexo well they are "perfect" within the limits of precision defined by the language. floating points aren't actual numbers, but rather representations of an approximate number good to within 10 or so decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a dynamically typed language. The type of a variable is defined by the value it contains.

So, In your code, the variables `shirtNo`, `bearNo`, `pillowNo` most probably contain string values - because they seems to be read from HTML text elements.

In order to perform mathematical operations, the variables must contain `number` values. You can convert a string value to a number by using the `Number` function.

```
Number(shirtNo)
```

Also, `$14` will not give it a Dollar value. A number is just a number in Javascript. The currency is only an interpretation.

So, you can rewrite your code like this:

```
 function doFunction(){

   var shirtNo, bearNo, c; 

   shirtNo =  document.getElementById("panda_shirt").value;
   bearNo = document.getElementById("panda_toy").value;
   pillowNo = document.getElementById("panda_pillow").value;


   estimateTotal = (14 * Number(shirtNo)) + (12 * Number(bearNo)) + (10 * Number(pillowNo));
  
   document.getElementById('estimateTotal').value = estimateTotal;
 }
```

However, it may not be that the user has entered a numerical value in the inputs. In that case the function `isNaN()` can tell you if any value is Not A Number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value of **bearNo** to an `int` or `float` number. Otherwise, it will be count as a string.
And **$14** doesn't work like this. You can't use a $ sign when multiplying with numbers.